# 'flutter run' won't let me choose my connected iOS device to run my application on - debugging works

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code, I can successfully debug my application on my connected iOS 16.6 (iPhone) device. I have been doing this for months, using USB debugging, and it is running fine.

Now, I would like to just run (not debug) my application.

My device's name 'iPhone of XXXX' shows up in the bottom right corner of VS code, as expected.

However, when I issue `flutter run` under VS code, the command won't let me choose my iOS device, why?

When I type `flutter devices`, again, the device is not shown.

How I can just run my application without debugging? Running the app by clicking on its icon from the iOS device is not supported (as mentionned in the Flutter docs - the application closes immediately).

Comment: Go on the iOs folder right-click on it and choose open in XCode, run it in XCode, and choose from XCode a simulator, you can see the error.

Comment: When I open Xcode, my iPhone is also detected and I can click the triangle icon (Play). The app runs fine. After that I can select Edit scheme, choose the Release build then run the app. However, can't I just do this from VS code?

Comment: if you want to release the app it's better to use Xcode

Comment: I can build a signed release from the command line using `flutter build ipa`. However, I can't just run the app from the flutter command line.

Comment: what's the error when you run (press F5) the project?